# Can't install pyspatialite with python3 and sqlite3

Tags: spatialite, python-3

I can't install pyspatialite. When I try it gives me this error:

```
pip install pyspatialite
Downloading/unpacking pyspatialite
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyspatialite (from versions: 
2.6.2-spatialite.2.3.1, 2.6.2-spatialite.2.4.0-4, 3.0.1-alpha-0)
Cleaning up...
No distributions matching the version for pyspatialite
Storing debug log for failure in /home/jenia/.pip/pip.log
```

The python interpreter that's installed in the virtualenv is 3.4.1.

When I run explicetly:

```
pip install pyspatialite==2.6.2-spatialite.2.4.0-4
```

I get this:

```
Running setup.py (path:/home/jenia/pip/app/build/pyspatialite/setup.py) egg_info for package pyspatialite
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "/home/jenia/pip/app/build/pyspatialite/setup.py", line 83
    print "Is sphinx installed? If not, try 'sudo easy_install sphinx'."
                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

File "/home/jenia/pip/app/build/pyspatialite/setup.py", line 83

print "Is sphinx installed? If not, try 'sudo easy_install sphinx'."

                                                                   ^

 SyntaxError: invalid syntax

 ----------------------------------------
 Cleaning up...
 Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /home/jenia/pip/app/build/pyspatialite
 Storing debug log for failure in /home/jenia/.pip/pip.log
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: Looks like a bug in the packaging. You can perhaps work around this by installing sphinx.